Algorithm to count adjacents of vertexes in a polyhedron
Is there an algorithm to count the adjacents of all the vertexes in a polyhedron defined by some linear equations?
In other words, I have a $A$ by $N$ matrix $V_{ai}$ with $N<A$, and a dimension-$A$ vector $v_a$. I need to find all the possible subsets $S_r$ of $\{1,2,\dots,A\}$ and corresponding dimension-$N$ vectors $z_i$, such that
(1) Rank$\{V_{ai}|a\in S_r\}=N$;
(2) $\sum_{i=1}^NV_{ai}z_i=v_a, a\in S_r$;
(3) $\sum_{i=1}^NV_{ai}z_i\neq v_a, a\notin S_r$.
It'll be best if there's any package that can achieve this.
